# Problem with circular dependencies (Cannot access X before initialisation)

Tags: typescript, cryptocurrency

I've come across an issue after solving [my other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516265/typeerror-import-wallet-default-is-not-a-constructor). After I fixed it, an issue regarding circular dependencies showed up:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Wallet' before initialization`

You can find the code on [GitHub](https://www.github.com/Archigan1/Shitcoin), as this issue regards several files. The error in question first points to `/src/Wallet.ts:1:1` and then to `/src/NETWORK_WALLET.ts:3:28` and `/src/Transaction.ts:3:28`. I attempted to move import statements around, and that solved one particular case, but not another, and upon doing that same to that chain, failed to solve any at all.

For example, `Wallet.ts`:

```
import { generateKeyPairSync } from "crypto";
import Chain from "./Chain";
import Transaction from "./Transaction";
```

`Transaction.ts`:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { createHash, createSign, createVerify } from "crypto";
import NETWORK_WALLET from "./NETWORK_WALLET";
import Wallet from "./Wallet";
import Chain from "./Chain";
```

and `NETWORK_WALLET.ts`:

```
import Wallet from "./Wallet";

const NETWORK_WALLET = new Wallet();

export default NETWORK_WALLET;
```

Comment: Please put a [mre] _in the question_.

Comment: [Holy grail of solving circular dependency problems](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Thanks to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71738142/problem-with-circular-dependencies-cannot-access-x-before-initialisation#comment126778662_71738142) by [@kellys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/kellys), and an hour of debugging due to my cluelessness, I was able to make a file named `internal.ts` in my home directory, which imported all classes from my modules and exported them all at once, which loads all of the modules before any are called inside others, and also giving me the ability to choose the load order. This saved me a lot of time trying to work out my own solution, and really neatens up my code.

Here's **internal.ts:**

```
import { getHash, makeRoot, calculateHash } from './src/utils';
import Block from './src/Block';
import Chain from './src/Chain';
import Transaction from './src/Transaction';
import Wallet from './src/Wallet';
import MerkleNode from './src/MerkleNode';
import MerkleTree from './src/MerkleTree';
import NETWORK_WALLET from './src/NETWORK_WALLET';
import { create } from './src/newWallet';

export { getHash, makeRoot, calculateHash, Block, Chain, Transaction, Wallet, MerkleNode, MerkleTree, NETWORK_WALLET, create };
```

And I can load a module in another file, such as I do in **/src/Chain.ts:**

```
import { calculateHash, NETWORK_WALLET, Block, Transaction } from '../internal';
// ...
```